# Dimensional analysis of the equation $s_{n}= u+ \frac{1}{2}(2n-1)a$

Tags: kinematics, dimensional-analysis

It is a question in my textbook to see if the equation

$s_{n}= u+ \frac{1}{2}(2n-1)a$

is dimensionally correct where $s_{n}$ is the distance travelled by a uniformly accelerating body with initial velocity $u$ and acceleration $a$ in the nth second.

The book says that the unit of $s_{n}$ is that of velocity as it is distance per second. I differ in reasoning because in the derivation of the formula the seconds unit of time is ignored, or, the original formula should be:

$s_{n}= u \cdot 1s+ \frac{1}{2}(2n \cdot 1s-1s^2)a$

The book is released by our government so I have my reasons for doubting my reasoning. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The equation for uniformly accelerated motion is $s=s_0 + v_0 t + 1/2 a t^2$. The above looks like an attempt at a numerical solution (?). You need to provide more context about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Nick I have clearly mentioned in the question that $s_{n}$ is the distance travelled in the n th second, or, from $n-1$ to $n$

Comment: If $s_n$ is a *distance*, it cannot have the units of velocity. If the book says that, it is certainly wrong.

Comment: @Nick I fear you misread the statement. $s_n\equiv (x(n ~sec) - x((n-1)~sec))/sec$ is an average velocity.

Comment: What statement? The OP maintains it's a distance, you maintain it's an average velocity. Notationally, if it is a velocity, it's misleading. Conceptually, I have a vague feeling that this is an Euler integration, perhaps with a midpoint method improvement? But it's far from clear to me that any part of the question can be taken at face value, so I was trying to get some clarification.

Comment: @Nick the question has nothing to do with numerical integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is correct. The confusion is probably because of exactly what the variables in the equation mean.

The "distance traveled in the $n$th second" is the distance between the positions at time $t = n$ and $t = n-1$. Using the standard SUVAT formula $s = s_0 + ut + \frac 1 2 at^2$, that means $$s_n = \left(s_0 + un + \tfrac 1 2 a n^2\right) - \left(s_0 + u(n-1) + \tfrac 1 2 a(n-1)^2\right)$$ which simplifies to the OP's equation.

You have to be careful about the dimensions of the "constants" here. The $\frac 1 2$'s are just numbers, but the $1$'s in the $(n-1)$ terms represent $1$ second, not the dimensionless number $1$.

So when you simplify $un - u(n-1)$ to just $u$, that really means "the velocity $u$ times $1$ second", which is a *distance*, not a *velocity*.

It may be more "correct" to write this as $u \cdot 1\text{s}$ instead of just $u$, as the OP proposes, but the book's notation is commonly used, so you need to get used to it. Writing $u \cdot 1\text{s}$ can also cause confusion if someone things that "s" is a variable, not an abbreviation for "seconds". And if they think the "$\cdot$" means a scalar product of two vectors (which the OP might not know about yet) that might cause even more confusion.

Comment: Ok - thanks for the explanation, although I do think a crystal ball had to be involved in getting from the OP's statement of the problem to your answer. In general, I think it's a good idea to keep $\Delta t$ factors around and set them to 1s at the very end.